# Yii 'limit' on related model's scope

Tags: php, mysql, yii, limit

I have a model called Guesses that has_many Comments. I'm making eager queries to this to then pass on as JSON as response to an API call.

The relations are obviously set between the two models and they are correct(one2many <=> belongs2)

I added a scope to Comments called 'api' like this:

```
public function scopes()
    {
        return array(
            'api' => array(
                'select' => 'id, comment, date',
                'limit'=>3,
                'order'=>'date DESC',
                'together'=>true,
            ),
        );
    }
```

And I'm running the following one-liner query:

```
$data = Guesses::model()->with('comments:api')->findAll();
```

The issue here is that when calling the 'api' scope using a with('relation'), the **limit** property simply doesn't apply.
I added the 'together'=>true there for another type of scope, plus I hear it might help. It doesn't make a difference.

I don't need all the comments of all Guesses. I want the top 3 (or 5). I am also trying to keep the one-liner call intact and simple, manage everything through scopes, relations and parameterized functions so that the API call itself is clean and simple.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to achieve this, which i know.

1st. You can add limit to relation, for ex.

```
    'photos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Photo', 'companyId', 
                      'limit'=>3
                )
```

2nd. You can call limit results when call relation, for ex.

```
$model->photos(array('limit' => 4));
```

Maybe there are some other methods, but i don't know them.

Comment: Afraid the limit in the relation definition is being ignored just the same and I can't only call the relation with the array limit "$model->photos(array('limit' => 4));" because I need to call it with the "api" scope. So it has to be $data = $model->with('photos:api');

Comment: When you call `$data = Guesses::model()->with('comments:api')->findAll();` you use lazy loading, not selecting all records by now. In lazy loading limiting relation data is impossible, that's it. I showed you what limits possible. It's the only way to limit relation from what i searched and saw. So if you will change some logic, you can achieve it. When selecting records in cycle with your AR object use `$model->comments(array('limit'=>3))`. It will work, and yeah limit in scope is useless.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes), that should be ok..

My only suggestions would be:

```
$data = Guesses::model()->with(
   array('comments'=>array('scopes'=>array('api')))
)->findAll();
```

or:

```
$data = Guesses::model()->findAll(array(
  'with'=>array('comments'=>array('scopes'=>array('api')))
));
```

but that should be the same logic. I don't think `together` will help you.. it is true by default.

**Update**

These examples are taken straight from the [relational documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

```
$posts=Post::model()->with('comments:recently:approved')->findAll();
```

or since 1.1.7:

```
$posts=Post::model()->with(array(
    'comments'=>array(
        'scopes'=>array('recently','approved')
    ),
))->findAll();
```

or since 1.1.7

```
$posts=Post::model()->findAll(array(
    'with'=>array(
        'comments'=>array(
            'scopes'=>array('recently','approved')
        ),
    ),
));
```

and lazy-loading:

```
$approvedComments = $post->comments('comments:approved');
```

Which suggests that your code should work.. what query is being run in your trace?
Do you have any default scopes that you haven't posted? Are their any extra options defined in your relation? I have had trouble with both of these interfering with named scopes.

Comment: Documentation also says `Note: Named scopes can only be used with class-level methods. That is, the method must be called using ClassName::model().`
Thinking logically, a 'with' relation LEFT JOINS the table and in a query there's no way to set limit to the joined table results unless you write a nested MySQL query which I think Yii doesn't.
Neither of your suggestions worked when calling upon the scope of a relation using 'with'. I mean it does, it just doesn't apply the limit condition.

Comment: @pethee Yeah, named scopes can be used in a relation call too.. I think Yii should handle limit according to the docs in my update above. Can you answer the questions I have appended as well?

Comment: Thank you. I got an answer below from ineersa confirming what I thought was the truth. All these you posted are correct and work. But they will all ignore the "limit" when in a scope called through a relation. I have no default scopes (on purpose), and the scope itself is applied (order, select clauses are working), only limit is ignored. As I can tell it's impossible to do simply with relations and scopes - for a lazy loading.